# \pageref points to wrong page number

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm having a small problem with `\pageref{}` in LaTeX. I have a quite a large document, and towards the end I point to specific pages in the text. Using `hyperref`, the link jumps to the correct part of the document, but the actual page number is incorrect.

This is slightly similar (but kind of opposite) to this problem:

[LaTeX hyperref link goes to wrong page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745731/latex-hyperref-link-goes-to-wrong-page)

I implemented the solution there (`\refstepcounter{dummy}`), but to no avail. The targets of the `\pageref`s are generally text. One such example is:

```
...these\refstepcounter{dummy}\label{s82:rclass} classifications are....
```

later referenced by:

```
\S\ref{s82:richness}, p.\pageref{s82:rclass}
```

Where the first ref is the section the text lives in. I'm using the following (if this helps), in addition to `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

I should note that this works correctly towards the start of the document (where I reference forwards rather than backwards, though I'm not sure if that's significant or not). That said, it also does not work when I attempt a reference forwards in the same chapter (document is a thesis)

Many thanks in advance for your help. I would like to include a minimal working example, but the referencing works as expected for the small document I tested. I would be keen to solicit suggestions as to what the problem could be, however.

Comment: I assume you did the obvious checks: (1) there is no "Rerun to get cross references right" in the log file, (2) no warnings about duplicate labels. Do you use `\pagenumbering{..}`? (It should still work)

Comment: Difficult to call without a minimal example. Maybe some package interferes with the `\label`, which is very sectioning/caption specific. For links to general text parts the `zref` package might be better suited. It is from the same author as `hyperref` and works well with it.

Comment: @Christian Lindig - ah... strange. After correcting a couple of (unrelated, or so I thought) dupes (2), I got (1) in the log file. Odd. My rendering procedure is: pdflatex ; bibtex ; pdflatex ; pdflatex. How many do I need after bibtex?

Comment: @Dave Theoretically it is possible that you never reach a fix point but that is very unlikely. I am not sure, but at most three runs of `pdflatex` after `bibtex` should suffice.

Comment: @Christian Lindig - looks like three's the magic number for me. I guess I'll have to drum my fingers on the desk a while longer! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Dave: This question should be resolved in one way another. @Christian could post his comment as an answer and you can accept it or the questions could be closed by a moderator.

Comment: I am compiling with XeLatex.  I get the CORRECT page number, but the hyperlink send me to the first page of the chapter that contains that page, not the actual page.   I want to use these correct page numbers, but I'd like to either (1) turn off the generated link, or (2) correct the link to actually send to the correct page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you did the obvious checks:

- there is no *Rerun to get cross references right* in the log file,
- and no warnings about duplicate labels.

Do you use `\pagenumbering{..}`? (It should still work). Rerun LaTeX as indicated. Theoretically it is possible that you never reach a fix point but that is very unlikely. I am not sure, but at most three runs of `pdflatex` after `bibtex` should suffice.

Answer (score 13):

The standard problem I have found over the years is that people do not understand the scope of the standard latex `\label` commands and that you must take 2 (or more) runs to get it right. Below is figure that I use to explain the scope to people new to Latex. Maybe something like this can be put in a FAQ or Wiki
[image]